# What is the proper way to include a partial view in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a form for our users to update account info.  I have a package built so that users can create custom lists to choose qualifications from to display on their profiles.  I have a partial view created for the custom lists that loops through all of the lists for that entity type to get which ones to display on the form.

The problem i'm having is that the @include() only works when I put it in the @section('content) area, but then the rest of the content from the including blade is not shown, only what is included.  If i put the include in its own section, it doesnt show.

Having the include in the same section as the rest of my code like this:

```
@extends($layout)

@section('content')
<form>
     <label>Name</Label>
     <input type="text" name="first_name">

     <label>Last Name</Label>
     <input type="text" name="last_name">

     <label>Email</Label>
     <input type="text" name="email_address">
</form>
@include('Package::path.to.partial')
@endsection
```

Results in something like:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div class="container-fluid>
               <Partial Package Code>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

If I have the include in it's own section, like below, only what is in the "content" section is displayed:

```
@extends($layout)

@section('content)
<form>
     <label>Name</Label>
     <input type="text" name="first_name">

     <label>Last Name</Label>
     <input type="text" name="last_name">

     <label>Email</Label>
     <input type="text" name="email_address">
</form>
@endsection
@section('custom_list')
     @include('Package::path.to.partial')
@endsection
```

Results in something like:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div class="container-fluid">
                 <form>
                      <label>Name</Label>
                      <input type="text" name="first_name">

                      <label>Last Name</Label>
                      <input type="text" name="last_name">

                      <label>Email</Label>
                      <input type="text" name="email_address">
                 </form>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really struggling to comprehend your set up from the description. Can you post some code, please?

Comment: @MartinBean Sorry about that, added details! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have the include in it's own section, like below, only what is in the "content" section is displayed

That’s to be expected. You’re redefining the `content` section in your partial, so it’ll just override that section’s content. Instead, partials should be exactly that: partial content. So just put whatever mark-up you want in your partial Blade template like you would with vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 0):

That package's partial view is defining its own `@section('content')`.

In the first scenario, the package's `content` section is overriding yours. Pretty lousy of that package to use such a generic name.

In the second, it doesn't show up because you are defining the `custom_list` section but you are not yielding its contents anywhere. You need to add `@yield('custom_list')` to your layout template.

Unfortunately that will still not solve your problem, because the `content` [naming conflict still exists](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-section-multiple-times/replies/78669).

Your best bet is to rename your section to something else.

```
@section('app')
    <... your fields ...>

    @include('Package::path.to.partial')

    @yield('content')
@stop
```

Update your layout template(s) to yield the new section name

```
@yield('app')
```

Better yet, fork that package, change their section name to `[package_name]:content` and submit a pull request.